# How to put viewbag value as a variable in javascript/ jquery?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, viewbag

I try to put two variable in JQuery which came from viewbags :

```
        $("#btnAdd").click(function () {
        var url = dev + "/Legacy/PutContentInThematic";
        var GroupingId = $("#GroupingId_Dialog").val();            
        var Title = $("#Title_Dialog").val();
        var Synopsis = $("#Description_Dialog").val();
        var image = $("#Image_Dialog").val();
        var ThematicId = @ViewBag.thematicid //Here i can't put ';'
        var ThematicName =  @ViewBag.Name

        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            cache: false,
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                GroupingId: GroupingId,
                ThematicId: ThematicId,
                Title: Title,
                Synopsis: Synopsis,
                Image: image,
                ThematicName: ThematicName
            }
        });
    });
```

The problem concerns the two last variables "ThematicId" And "ThematicName", it is impossible to put ';' at the end, so the second variable ThematicName don't work.

I try to put this variable out of the function, but i doesn't work anymore. Have you and idea to fix it or an other solution for this Ajax call ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to write it this way:

```
var ThematicId = parseInt('@ViewBag.thematicid');
var ThematicName =  '@ViewBag.Name';
```

Comment: This only works if both ViewBag values are strings, what if `thematicid` is an integer?

Comment: @Ashley posted how to do for `int`

Comment: you can also check to see if the variable contains only integer... http://pietschsoft.com/post/2008/01/14/JavaScript-intTryParse-Equivalent

Comment: @Julien698 welcome, `parseInt()` will work, if the value is ``int`` otherwise it will not, so consider @Olluwafemi commented link as well which suggests

Comment: You're right, but in my case i'm lucky because Thematicid is an int.

Answer (score 3):

```
var ThematicId = @(ViewBag.thematicid); //For int
var ThematicName =  '@ViewBag.Name';   //For string
```

Comment: For the first variable it don't work for me it says that ';' at the end is an error, so i use the solution with parseInt

Comment: @Julien698 Where does it say this is an error? The view should be valid with this syntax.

Comment: the error is on the ; at the end of the first variable

Comment: @Julien698 When you try and run the website what is the error message you are given?

Comment: The Website run without error, but is't juste in the page before to run. http://imageshack.com/a/img673/7188/A3nPwV.jpg

Comment: @Julien698 from the attached screenshot I can see you have written `(@ViewBag.thematicid);` and not `@(ViewBag.thematicid);`